# Two questions on the `monthly` package

Tags: tufte, calendar

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{monthly}

\begin{document}

\begin{fullwidth}
    \begin{monthly}
        {}{}
        1 May 2014 to 31 May 2014
    \end{monthly}
\end{fullwidth}


\end{document}
```

1. As you will see if you compile it, the calendar occupies only the regular width of the `tufte-handout` text block, despite the `fullwidth` environment. Is there a way to make it recognize the `fullwidth` environment?
2. Is there a way to change the color of the calendar cells (as opposed to the type)? Say, e.g., I wanted all the Mondays to be colored gray (i.e., 20% black or so). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question you posed:

Try adding the following lines to the preamble of your document (after you've loaded the `monthly` package):

```
\makeatletter
\def\mon@settablewidth{%
  \setlength{\mon@tablewidth}{\@tufte@fullwidth}%
}
\makeatother
```

I'm not sure about your second question. I've never actually used the `monthly` package and had to download the source code from the web.